# Store the URL of the previous page in PHP?

Tags: php, http, url

In my website, after a user selects login from some page, and after logging in I want to redirect him to the previous page.

If I define HTTP referer variable (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`), on the login page it wont work because for form validation, it will again come back to login page and referer variable will be changed.

e.g.

page1.php -> login.php(referer=page1) -> login action validation(referer=login.php).

How to solve this?

Comment: if u can give more detail will be helpful

Comment: don't realy on HTTP_REFERER, use a hidden form field for this.

Comment: are u using session for storing login information?

Answer (score 4):

Use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

**login.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["referer"] = $_GET['referer'];
```

**page2.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["referer"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']

[$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

your **login.php** file should be like this.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userName'] && $_SESSION['Password']))
{
    header('location:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
else{
    */ your login code /*
}
```